# Can't get folder removed from Dropbox exclude list

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, dropbox

I am running Dropbox on a linux server (no GUI) and I can't get Dropbox to remove a specific folder from its exclude list. I've installed the command line interface. Previously I ran `dropbox exclude myfolder` but when I subsequently tried to remove the folder from the exclude list, this is what happened:

`dropbox exclude remove myfolder`
and then
`dropbox exclude list`
And it still prints:
`myfolder`

I don't know how/where to begin debugging. Is this exclude list written to a file somewhere that I can manually modify? Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command from the Dropbox root directory. For whatever reason the remove command seems to take better when executed from there.